# Sails.js matching up endpoint methods to http methods (GET, POST)

Tags: sails.js

I'm working through the documentation on [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/), and have created a basic dev instance according to their "Getting Started" guide:

```
$ sudo npm -g install sails
$ sails new testProject
$ sails generate users
$ sails lift
```

These four simple commands will install the platform, create a project, and create the model `users` as designed.

From my browser, using the default installation port, I can now access `http://localhost:1337/users` and receive an empty JSON array `[]` as expected.

Now, should I wish to *create* a new user, [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) best practice dictates that I should use the `POST` method. `POST` does indeed work, **however** out of the box, Sails *also* allows you to perform `GET http://localhost:1337/users/create` to generate a new user object.

Reading through their documentation, I have been unable to determine a way of limiting which HTTP methods are allowed to perform various tasks. Is this in the documentation? Or can someone explain where in the Sails stack this (should|could) be managed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sails.js provides you with those [shortcuts](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/controllers/routing-to-controllers) letting you to operate using only GET method for development purposes only. You can disable those in production, if you want, using the configuration noted in the docs:

> By default, Sails will create a blueprint action route for each action
>   in a controller, so that a GET request to
>   `/:controllerIdentity/:nameOfAction` will trigger the action. If the
>   example controller in the previous section was saved as
>   `api/controllers/SayController.js`, then the `/say/hi` and `/say/bye` routes
>   would be made available by default whenever the app was lifted. If the
>   controller was saved under the subfolder `/we`, then the routes would be
>   `/we/say/hi` and `/we/say/bye`. See the [blueprints documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api) for more
>   information about Sails’ automatic route binding.
>
> Besides the default
>   routing, Sails allows you to manually bind routes to controller
>   actions using the config/routes.js file. Some examples of when you
>   might want to use explicit routes are:
>
> - When you want to use separate
>     actions to handle the same route path, based on the HTTP method (aka
>     verb). The aforementioned action blueprint routes bind all request
>     methods for a path to a given action, including GET, POST, PUT,
>     DELETE, etc.